Why is creationism even an issue?
There isn't a defined debate between creationism and evolution, or even that evolution is the opposite position to creationism.
For example,

Evolution doesn't need to happen for creationism to be wrong. Any other process in the universe can create life without evolution because it was never defined how evolution works.

Assuming we call whatever process in (1) "evolution", which is different from natural selection or anything else, where is the prime mover argument? Has science provided any answer to the prime mover problem?

Assuming science has no answer to the prime mover problem, what do scientists think caused the universe to exist, and if they have no answer doesn't this lose to any other alternate explanation?


What are the parameters of the debate?


"it was never defined how evolution works" - the way in which evolution works is very well-defined and has been observed to happen in human timescales (through artificial selection processes). 2. The prime mover argument fails when you consider two masses at rest relative to one another that, without anything "causing" their motion, gravitate and start moving. I hope we don't need to consider whether gravity is real or not. 3. Science does have an answer to the prime mover problem, which is that things don't need another thing to cause motion other than basic physics.


If 3 is wrong then 2 is wrong (since 3 is just me restating 2), and if 2 is wrong, you will have to explain why things initially at rest start gravitating towards one another without another object intervening.

Philosophically speaking, gravity isn't a thing. It's just a property of reality that massive objects do certain things to the geometry of spacetime which manifests as an attractive force. It's not a being or a real force or anything more than just a fact of the Universe.

I don't see why. My point is that evolution is much better-understood than your post seems to suggest and that the prime mover argument is invalid, because things are in fact capable of spontaneously entering into motion without an external object intervening.

That's a good answer to a 2000 year old philosophical debate

"... and if they have no answer doesn't this lose to any other alternate explanation?" No.

Evolution and the prime mover argument have nothing to do with each other. Evolution is about biology, the prime mover argument, as an alternative to the big bang theory, adresses astrophysics. Even the apparition of life isn't part of evolution, as evolution is a phenomenon independent from how the first cells came to be, be it creation, panspermia or abiogenesis. The question overall shows a lack of prior research.

Creationism was selected as the last big gap that the gods of the gaps of many Christians hides within. God does not make babies anymore, does not bring or cure diseases, does not control weather or natural disasters, did not create the universe in 5 days, did not place earth in the middle of the universe, did not put humanity first on the planet (the dinosaurs ruled for 200 million years, humanity for less than 5000 years).
So one by one, the gaps that had been attributed to gods were closed by science, with no trace of gods.
That is the conflict between evolution and creationism that raged roughly between 200years and 100years ago when discoveries from geology, biology, archeology, paleontology, cosmology, physics, chemistry and so on were gathered an an unprecedented scale and combined. Then creationism lost due to the overwhelming evidence, humanity moved on, and today only a minority of rural southern north-americans still cling to those ideas as a identity yielding concept to rally around. The debate also coincided with racial tensions in the USA, and since the Ku-Klux-Klan is unfashionable today, white supremacists can now self identify with Creationism that had foe a long time been a justification for slavery (The US Bible belt is concentrated around the US states that abolished slavery and segregation last). Today it's merely the figurehead of a political issue, not a philosophical issue anymore.

Bizarre collection of political sidetracks for what is asking about the prime mover problem.

Bizarre way of asking about the prime mover problem by focusing on creationism vs evolution.

As far as I can tell, creationism came out of biblical literalism, which I strongly suspect is also primarily a US phenomenon these days. (If it isn't, I would be interested in knowing where else it has arisen. I have heard several theories about how US style religious conservatism arose, and putting it in context might help me understand that.)

It is in the definition of creationism that it is contrary to evolution.

Perhaps there are flavours of creationism with varying definitions?

You can't define your own position as sole opposition to a specific form of some tangentially opposed ideology.

@Faraz I don't think Alistair is a creationist, so you're telling the wrong person.

You can't define evolution as the opposite of creationism. That doesn't work. There can be a third position where both are wrong.

@Faraz TKoL is correct that I am not a creationist.  The "not" is really deserving of all-caps, but I am trying to wean them out of my writing style.  Also, Faraz... I haven't defined anything, and I try my best not to do that, since it leads to miscommunication and misunderstanding.  And that is why I got the Google/Oxford definition so my answer would be based on the standard accepted definition.  (new comment to address your 3rd)

@Faraz I wholeheartedly agree, there is potential for a third or more options... simulation
(though related to creationism by way of a "programmer" instead of designer).  But... we have no evidence of creation.  We have evidence for evolution.  I still agree... maybe (and probably) more to it.  I don't think the definition is.. "creationism is not evolution" the definition is creationism is not natural... such as... evolution (a natural example)

Yes eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Earth_creationism Which has to write off the geological record as god testing our faith..!

OP : "What are the parameters of the debate?"
These are the parameters demonstrated in the antinomy of causality, laid out by Kant in the 18th century.
Thesis: eternal existence with infinite time can never arrive here, therefore some spontaneous event ('freedom') must have been able to happen.
Antithesis: a spontaneous event contradicts the principle of causality.
No solution to the above antinomy, therefore simply proceed from where one is.
The Meiklejohn translation is quoted below (A445/B473), from The Project Gutenberg, with the section titles to help situate where this is in the book.
The Critique of Pure Reason
I. Transcendental Doctrine of Elements
Second Part—TRANSCENDENTAL LOGIC
SECOND DIVISION—TRANSCENDENTAL LOGIC
TRANSCENDENTAL DIALECTIC—BOOK II—OF THE DIALECTICAL PROCEDURE OF PURE REASON
Chapter II. The Antinomy of Pure Reason
Section II. Antithetic of Pure Reason

THIRD CONFLICT OF THE TRANSCENDENTAL IDEAS. THESIS.
Causality according to the laws of nature, is not the only causality
operating to originate the phenomena of the world. A causality of
freedom is also necessary to account fully for these phenomena.
PROOF.
Let it be supposed, that there is no other kind of causality than that
according to the laws of nature. Consequently, everything that happens
presupposes a previous condition, which it follows with absolute
certainty, in conformity with a rule. But this previous condition must
itself be something that has happened (that has arisen in time, as it
did not exist before), for, if it has always been in existence, its
consequence or effect would not thus originate for the first time, but
would likewise have always existed. The causality, therefore, of a
cause, whereby something happens, is itself a thing that has happened.
Now this again presupposes, in conformity with the law of nature, a
previous condition and its causality, and this another anterior to the
former, and so on. If, then, everything happens solely in accordance
with the laws of nature, there cannot be any real first beginning of
things, but only a subaltern or comparative beginning. There cannot,
therefore, be a completeness of series on the side of the causes which
originate the one from the other. But the law of nature is that
nothing can happen without a sufficient à priori determined cause. The
proposition therefore—if all causality is possible only in accordance
with the laws of nature—is, when stated in this unlimited and general
manner, self-contradictory. It follows that this cannot be the only
kind of causality.
From what has been said, it follows that a causality must be admitted,
by means of which something happens, without its cause being
determined according to necessary laws by some other cause preceding.
That is to say, there must exist an absolute spontaneity of cause,
which of itself originates a series of phenomena which proceeds
according to natural laws—consequently transcendental freedom, without
which even in the course of nature the succession of phenomena on the
side of causes is never complete.
ANTITHESIS.
There is no such thing as freedom, but everything in the world happens
solely according to the laws of nature.
PROOF.
Granted, that there does exist freedom in the transcendental sense, as
a peculiar kind of causality, operating to produce events in the
world—a faculty, that is to say, of originating a state, and
consequently a series of consequences from that state. In this case,
not only the series originated by this spontaneity, but the
determination of this spontaneity itself to the production of the
series, that is to say, the causality itself must have an absolute
commencement, such that nothing can precede to determine this action
according to unvarying laws. But every beginning of action presupposes
in the acting cause a state of inaction; and a dynamically primal
beginning of action presupposes a state, which has no connection—as
regards causality—with the preceding state of the cause—which does
not, that is, in any wise result from it. Transcendental freedom is
therefore opposed to the natural law of cause and effect, and such a
conjunction of successive states in effective causes is destructive of
the possibility of unity in experience and for that reason not to be
found in experience—is consequently a mere fiction of thought.
We have, therefore, nothing but nature to which we must look for
connection and order in cosmical events. Freedom—independence of the
laws of nature—is certainly a deliverance from restraint, but it is
also a relinquishing of the guidance of law and rule. For it cannot be
alleged that, instead of the laws of nature, laws of freedom may be
introduced into the causality of the course of nature. For, if freedom
were determined according to laws, it would be no longer freedom, but
merely nature. Nature, therefore, and transcendental freedom are
distinguishable as conformity to law and lawlessness. The former
imposes upon understanding the difficulty of seeking the origin of
events ever higher and higher in the series of causes, inasmuch as
causality is always conditioned thereby; while it compensates this
labour by the guarantee of a unity complete and in conformity with
law. The latter, on the contrary, holds out to the understanding the
promise of a point of rest in the chain of causes, by conducting it to
an unconditioned causality, which professes to have the power of
spontaneous origination, but which, in its own utter blindness,
deprives it of the guidance of rules, by which alone a completely
connected experience is possible.
OBSERVATIONS ON THE THIRD ANTINOMY. ON THE THESIS.
The transcendental idea of freedom is far from constituting the entire
content of the psychological conception so termed, which is for the
most part empirical. It merely presents us with the conception of
spontaneity of action, as the proper ground for imputing freedom to
the cause of a certain class of objects. It is, however, the true
stumbling-stone to philosophy, which meets with unconquerable
difficulties in the way of its admitting this kind of unconditioned
causality.

Having laid out the antinomy Kant's idea of "simply proceeding from where one is" is suggested in the fragment below (A340/B398), as he grasps the "unconditioned necessity" that holds together the faculty of apperception.
TRANSCENDENTAL DIALECTIC—BOOK II—OF THE DIALECTICAL PROCEDURE OF PURE REASON

from the totality of the conditions of thinking objects in general, in
so far as they can be given, the absolute synthetical unity of all
conditions of the possibility of things in general; that is, from
things which I do not know in their mere transcendental conception, I
conclude a being of all beings which I know still less by means of a
transcendental conception, and of whose unconditioned necessity I can
form no conception whatever. This dialectical argument I shall call
the ideal of pure reason.

